# Google JSAPI function can not be accessed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, frontend

I am trying to move this piece of Google chart example code to

```
$(document).ready(function () {});
```

Right now it is placed in the script tag right after the Google JSAPI script and it works, like so:

```
<!--Google JSAPI-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
            ['Work', 11],
            ['Eat', 2],
            ['Commute', 2],
            ['Watch TV', 2],
            ['Sleep', 7]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: question,
            backgroundColor: '#CFCFCF'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('SS_piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

</script>
```

This is in my page_tail, just before closing body tag. But as soon as I put the code inside the

```
$(document).ready(function () {});
```

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: google.visualization.arrayToDataTable is not a function

```
<!--Google JSAPI-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
            ['Work', 11],
            ['Eat', 2],
            ['Commute', 2],
            ['Watch TV', 2],
            ['Sleep', 7]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: question,
            backgroundColor: '#CFCFCF'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('SS_piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

});

</script>
```

I have some other code sitting along in the $(document).ready function, is it possible I have code conflict, or is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to move the callback

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    drawChart();
});
```

or JS native

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", drawChart);
```